# Android MVVM where to store data?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvvm, android-mvvm

I have an activity with 4 fragments, on each of the fragments the user inputs a string and then moves on to the next one. 
So far I have a viewModel for every fragment and I pass each input as an argument that then I store in the viewModel.

My question is, should I just have a single viewModel where I store all of this inputs? Or is ok this way? Is there a better solution?

Comment: How exactly do you _"pass each input as an argument"_? Through a `Bundle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the viewmodels serve only the purpose of storing the data, you could create a shared view model in the activity and use it in all of the fragments, this way you can access any variable in all the fragments.